# How do I take a backup of a sqlite data base?

Tags: sqlite

Please help me understand how to take a backup of a sqlite database?

Comment: I'm not fully convinced this belongs on serverfault since the answer is actually to use the online backup API. If the answer was to shut down clients then copy the DB file, then yes, that would be the case.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite has a [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) for exactly this purpose. If you can guarantee that no-one is changing the database while you're backing it up, then you can simply copy the file.

But, if you want to ensure data integrity and still allow applications to access your database during the backup process, this API is what you need.